# How to use a different color for the required indicator in Vaadin 23

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to display the required indicator always red for several fields, I tried to set this via

```css
:host(.required-field)::part(required-indicator)::after {
   color: var(--dg-color-red);
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

I should apply for all kind of input fields if the class `required-field` is set and the field marked as required (`setRequired(true)`).

Is this possible?

Comment: Where did you place that css code?

Comment: And how does it not work? Gets your style picked up? Does something else override it? Inspect in the dev-console of your browser should help to find those things out.

Comment: Also is this Vaddin 24?

Comment: The code is placed within the general style.css of the theme to test if it works. I am using Vaadin 23. The color of the indicator of the field is not red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can supply a global variable to style the required indicator for the whole application. Add the following to your styles.css inside your custom theme.

```
html {
  --lumo-required-field-indicator-color: red;
}
```